# reloaddata() over performBatchUpdates for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionview, reloaddata

do you think its a good idea to use "reloadData()" in "viewwillAppear" or in "viewWillTransition". We use performBatchUpdates in both places right now and it has given us a lot of crashes, because we don't exactly get which rows have been deleted or which rows have been added.

Shabri

Comment: How can you not know which rows have been added/removed?

Comment: @SanderSaelmans, because there is a chance that the entire data source being built again while the phone is changing transitions. but do tell me one thing, do you think its heavy on the compiler calling a "reloadData()" at "viewwillAppear" or "viewwilltransition"?